# In PHP is it possible to create an interface alias as opposed to a class alias?

Tags: php, interface, alias

OK, this is an extremely easy question to answer, but I'm just asking it because the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/it/function.class-alias.php) does not specify the answer, and this answer could help someone googling around for this information.

My question is, in PHP, is it possible to set up an interface alias as opposed to a class alias?

Comment: Welll.. Yeah, the same way you'd create any class alias

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course it's possible. The following code demonstrates this:

```php
interface A {

  public function foo();

}

class_alias('A', 'B');

class FooB implements B {
    
  public function foo() {

    echo "Hello B.\n";

  }

}

$fooB = new FooB();
$fooB->foo();
```

Output from https://3v4l.org/MNMFV (for 5.3.0 - 7.2.0):

```
Hello B.
```

Older versions don't yet have the [`class_alias()`](https://www.php.net/class_alias) function.

Comment: You might be interested in namespaces. They allow great aliasing